# find birational maps of a hypersurface onto $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider $$Y = V(y^2-x^3) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$$

Now, $\phi: \mathbb{A} \to Y, t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$
is a birational map,
but the pullback $\phi^\ast: K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3) \to K[t], x \mapsto t^2, y \mapsto t^3$, is not an isomorphism of K-algebras.

(Do we say: $\phi$ is not an "isomorphism of varieties"?)

Now if we localize in the origin we get an isomorphism of the local rings at $0$:
$(K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3))_{(x,y)} \rightarrow K[t,t^{-1}]$, which gives us the "rational" parametrization $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$.

Is this correct?

Now I would like to handle the following more complicated example:

Consider the surface $X = V(y(x^2+z^2)-x) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^3$.

How to find here a local birational map from $X$ at $0$ onto $\mathbb{A}^2$ at $0$?

Of course we cannot simply take $\displaystyle (x,y,z) \mapsto \left(x,\frac{x}{x^2+z^2},z\right)$ because we get $0$-denominator in the origin.

What is the usual strategy to find the desired birational map?
How to find a good direction of projection?

Comment: Correct, $\phi$ is not an isomorphism of varieties: you can prove directly that it has no inverse by writing $K[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3)$ as $K[t^2, t^3]$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question "Is this correct ?"  after the sentence "Now if we localize in the origin we get an isomorphism of the local rings..."
is *no* for two reasons:

I) The local ring of $\mathbb A^1_K$ at zero is *not* $K[t,t^{-1}]$, but $K[t]_{(t)}$, a ring  in  which you may invert all polynomials not multiple of $t$, whereas in $K[t,t^{-1}]$ it is almost the opposite: you can only invert the powers of $t$!
Anyway, $K[t,t^{-1}]$ has infinitely many maximal ideals [even for a finite field $K$], and is thus not local.

II) Even taking I) into account, $\phi ^\ast$ does not give an isomorphism of the local rings.
Actually the local rings  $K[t]_{(t)}$ and $K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3))_{(x,y)}$  are not isomorphic at all
since (for example) $K[t]_{(t)}$ is a PID whereas $K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3))_{(x,y)}$ is not  a UFD.

Answer (score 2):

To answer part of your question, a birational map (or, a little bit more precisely, *morphism*) $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ is simply given by the formula $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,z)$.

Its inverse (*not* a morphism!) is given by something like your formula above: it is $\phi^{-1}: (x,z) \mapsto (x,\frac{x}{x^2+z^2},z)$. It's not hard to check that $\phi \circ \phi^{-1}$ and $\phi^{-1} \circ \phi$ are the identity functions on their respective domains of definition.

As you rightly say, this isn't defined at the point $(0,0)$, but that's ok: by definition a birational map from a variety only needs to be defined on a dense open subset of the variety. Here $\phi^{-1}$ is clearly defined on the subset $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \left\{  x = \pm \sqrt{-1} \ z \right\}$, which is dense in $\mathbb{A}^2$.